# Force fresh content, not from the cache

Tags: .htaccess, caching, optimization, browser

I used the following code in the htaccess to put my site under maintenance and show the visitors maintenance.html.

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
#RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

My site is now back online but now I see that all those browsers that tried to go on my site during the maintenance, they are still getting the maintenance.html.

It works if I clear the browser cache and I sort of understand why it is happening. I think the browser  caches the redirect and is still doing it.

How can I clear this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use mod_header to tell browsers not to cache your maintenance page.

```
Header merge Cache-Control no-cache
Header merge Cache-Control no-store
```

Comment: But the browser does not even go to the htaccess with the new codes to work now or does it?

Comment: the server processes the .htaccess files (for every request), not the browser